# Django Single File 404

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I'm a beginner in Django and I have put all my static files (html, css, js) in the static-only folder. This works fine, the template shows up neatly. However, I recently added a custom.css file and it's showing a 404 on `python manage.py runserver`. The other files in the same folder don't show a 404, however this does. I've typed the href path correctly and have rechecked again and again, but the error persists. Even `collectstatic` doesn't help.

Here's the base.html file which links to custom.css:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9H6c.jpg) Line 21 links to custom.css

Comment: post the code as how you are rendering it in the template

Answer (score 0):

`collectstatic` means collect all your static files, and put it into single place like nginx root directory.

You need to config `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` in `settings.py`, get more information at [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/).

Read the documentation first when start with some new tools. Elaborate documentation, I think :)

Comment: But why are other files in the same directory not showing 404?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! I was putting custom.css in `static-only` folder, which had some files named identical to files in the `static` folder. But the path was to `static folder`, not `static-only`. After putting my custom.css in `static`, it worked!